# Practicing PostgreSQL with C in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, postgresql, include

I would like to practice and prepare to use a server-based PostgreSQL database, for an upcoming school assignment.
The assignment will require me to write programs in C that can execute a variety of queries, as well as check their validity, etc.

I cannot find any definitive guide online to setting up PostgreSQL with Visual Studio and C.
I understand that I need to use a `libpq-fe` header file but when I download it from `PostgreSQL` and `#include` it, I still get linking errors and more. It's a mess.

Can someone guide me (and future users with this problem) through the process of setting this up?

Comment: ["Building libpq Programs"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-build.html) should give you an idea what's required.

Answer (score 3):

You can't just download `libpq-fe.h`  and expect to use it without anything else.

You must use *libpq* - include at least `libpq-fe.h`, link to `libpq.lib` and ensure that `libpq.dll` is present in the program runtime path. On Visual Studio that means editing your include path and library path, then adding libpq to the linker list.

I usually do [a source build of PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/install-windows.html) when I'm working with libpq, but I'm pretty sure the library and headers are included in the binary install as well. Check the install directory.

Comment: Hi Craig, I tried what feels like everything; I downloaded [all the header files and libraries](http://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/), added the `include` folder to VS, added the `lib` file to the linker, but I still get `LNK2019 errors`. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @lmray Edit your question to show your exact configuration, **exact text of the errors**, explain how exactly you are setting up access to the headers and libraries, etc. Then comment here when done so I'm notified

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to read this : http://pqxx.org/development/libpqxx/browser/trunk/win32/INSTALL.txt

This will tell you how to install or build libpq on your computer.

Personally, I just install PostgreSQL for Windows from the PostgreSQL official website.

This should avoid the need for building libpq.

Now that you have all the required files libpq.lib, libpq-fe.h,libpq.dll etc...You have to set the properties page of your VS project correctly i.e do exactly as specified in the INSTALL.TXT

Once the properties pages is set correctly add :

```
#include <string> 
#include "libpq-fe.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "libpq.lib")
```

For further information read this tutorial : http://www.askyb.com/cpp/c-postgresql-example/